# Python how to find a list of string that's inbetween 2 substring?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of string that's inbetween 2 string

```
text = """
something = $/I want to get this string A:blah blah 
somethingB = ($/I want to get this string as well B:blah blah blah)
"""

#I had this working to get the first found string
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""


find_between(text, '$/', ':')
# Result: I want to get this string A #
```

But I want to be able to search thru the string and get a list that found...something like

```
['I want to get this string A', 'I want to get this string as well B']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module(regular expression) to do it?

### --------------------------------------------------------- Solution: 1 -----------------------------------------------------------

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/1oc/1)

#### Code:

```
import re

text = """
something = $/I want to get this string A:blah blah 
somethingB = ($/I want to get this string as well B:blah blah blah)
"""

found = re.findall(r'\$\/(.+?)\:', text)
print found
```

#### Output:

```
['I want to get this string A', 'I want to get this string as well B']
```

#### RegEx Explained:

```
r'\$\/(.+?):'
```

> `\$`: This will match `$`(This character needs to be escaped).
>   `\/`: This will match `/`(This character needs to be escaped).
>   `(` : This represents the beginning of extraction.
>   `.` : This will match any character except a new line.
>   `+` : This represents match 1 or more previous character.
>   `?` : This will do a non-greedy search.
>   `)` : This represents the end of extraction.
>   `:` : This will match `:`.

### --------------------------------------------------------- Solution: 2 -----------------------------------------------------------

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/1oc/3)

#### Code:

```
import re

text = """
something = $/I want to get this string A:blah blah 
somethingB = ($/I want to get this string as well B:blah blah blah)
"""

def findBetween(first, second):
    first = '\\' + first[0] + '\\' + first[1]
    found = re.findall(r'' + first + '(.+?)' + second, text)
    print found

findBetween('$/', ':')
```

#### Output:

```
['I want to get this string A', 'I want to get this string as well B']
```

Comment: How does this generalize to arbitrary delimiters?   I think you need to show how to build a regex where the delimiters are contained in variables...

Comment: Thanks for commenthing, I've add an explaination

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear from your question, but assume you're looking for something like this...

```
def find_betweens(text,start,end):
    betweens = []
    for i in text.split(start):
        if end in i:
            betweens.append(i.split(end)[0])
    return betweens
```

To illustrate...

```
yo = "Hello. How are you? I'm good. You too?"
print find_betweens(yo, ".", "?")
```

will display

```
[' How are you', ' You too']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to continue on your attempt and a generalized example with `re.findall` as well:

```
import re

text = '''\
something = $/I want to get this string A:blah blah 
somethingB = ($/I want to get this string as well B:blah blah blah)
'''

def find_between1(s,first,last):
    first = re.escape(first)
    last = re.escape(last)
    return re.findall(first + r'(.*?)' + last, s)

def find_between2(s, first, last):
    start = 0
    L = []
    while True:
        try:
            start = s.index(first, start) + len(first)
            end = s.index(last, start)
            L.append(s[start:end])
            start = end + len(last)
        except ValueError:
            return L

print(find_between1(text,'$/',':'))
print(find_between2(text,'$/',':'))
```

Output:

```
['I want to get this string A', 'I want to get this string as well B']
['I want to get this string A', 'I want to get this string as well B']
```